# find values of children and append to post

Tags: jquery

I have a page with multiple divs. I want to traverse each div and grab value and attributes from its children and create an object ready for posting over ajax.

```
<div class="items" id="item1">
    <div class="form">
        <input type="checkbox" name="this" value="1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="that" value="0" />
        <select name="other">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="items" id="item2">
    <div class="form">
        <input type="checkbox" name="this" value="1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="that" value="0" />
        <select name="other">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="items" id="item3">
    <div class="form">
        <input type="checkbox" name="this" value="1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="that" value="0" />
        <select name="other">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to construct an object using jquery that will post to ajax like below. I want to grab the id from the parent div, and add the values from the inputs inside. like so....

```
   data[item1][this] = true
    data[item1][that] = false
    data[item1][other] = 'value'

    data[item2][this] = true
    data[item2][that] = false
    data[item2][other] = 'value'
```

So far i have this, but cant figure out how to grab the childrens values

```
$('.items').each(function(){
        ///
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code may help you

```
var json = {};

$('.items').each(function(){
     var id = this.id;
    json[this.id] = {};
    $(this).find("input, select").each(function(){
       json[this.name] = this.value;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little ugly, but it gets you what you need (it does rely on a click event, to make sure form data is actually filled in):

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
   // hold our objects, in preperation for stringification
   var results = []
   $('.form').each(function(){
       var form = {};
       $(this).children().each(function(){
         $item = $(this);
         console.log($item);
         form[$item.attr('name')] = $item.val();
       });
     results.push(form);
   });

  var jsoned = JSON.stringify(results);
  console.log(jsoned);
});
```

**<kbd>[codepen](http://codepen.io/NickTomlin/pen/BEHom)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could just each over the children like so:

```
$('div.items :input').each(function() {
  json[this.name] = $(this).val();
});
```

Or, replace ':input' with 'select' if you want to ensure selects only.